# How to debug Javascript as IE8 (with Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8, visual-studio-debugging, javascript-debugger

I need to debug a javascript that only occurs in IE8, my problem is that i've an Windows8.1 machine with IE11 and Visual Studio 2012.

I know that i could have (but don't have) a second machine with IE8 or a virtual machine, my question does not goes that way...

Is there any way to launch some debugger that acts as ie8? does Visualstudio have something for that?, any suggestions or alternatives?

When i'm trying to use devtools (emulating or compatibility mode) the error that i'm chasing does not happens. only happens in a real IE8

Comment: You need to use a VM or a machine running IE8. IE8 mode in browsers does not equal actual IE8 as you see.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way you will be able to legitimately reproduce the IE8 experience without using the actual browser. I have noticed that the IE8 Emulator doesnt authentically show the original IE8 experience. If you can get your hands on a machine running IE8 you can install the IE DOM Toolbar to help you debug the Javascript http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: Early versions of IE would work with Visual Studio for script debugging, and it's never something that worked for me. The least I could suggest for IE11 dev tools is to also ensure the user agent is specifically set to IE8 - it could be that some code path is finding IE11's signature UA elements.

Comment: Since IE8 is no longer supported by Microsoft; is there a specific reason you still need to support it?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker the company where i'm working still have IE8 as requirement for compatibility UI

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of the [free VM images](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools) available on [modern.ie](https://www.modern.ie/en-us)?

Hope this helps...

-- Lance